# How to install WordPress alongside conventional pages on a shared hosting system

Tags: installation

A club I belong to has had to move urgently to a new hosting service so I created a basic site using html & php. As the members who normally update the website do not have any scripting knowledge it would seem sensible to move to a CMS like WordPress. Our new host offers a one click installation but apparently this will not work alongside conventional pages - we were hoping to learn WordPress by using it to add new things to our site until skills developed to the state that it could be used for everything.

I assumed that it should be possible to do what I normally do and set up and test everything on my home PC and just use an ftp program for files and myphp for data uploads.

Any advice on how to move forward would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not manually install WordPress in a subdirectory? I.e., `example.com/wordpress/`

With the file directory being something like: `/public_html/wordpress/`

That will leave the conventional PHP site at root.

WordPress will generate an `.htaccess` file in `/wordpress/` for permalinks.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/before-install/howto-install/#detailed-instructions